# Is the following ungrammatical expression common in speech?

Tags: expressions, speech

> Don't be ashamed. It was cute, like a shy teenager.

I'm not very sure if this is a grammatical mistake, but I think the correct version would look like this:

> Don't be ashamed. It was cute, **you were/acted** like a shy teenager.

Is this a common mistake/omission in speech (by native English speakers)?

Comment: Yes, it's common. So common, in fact, that it would be excessive to call it "ungrammatical", or a "mistake".

Comment: @FF Bet you vote _Descriptive_.

Comment: I would interpret it as "*it was cute- [just] like a shy teenager [is cute*"  Nothing ungrammatical there.

Comment: @Edwin: Usually, but not always. (For example, I would ***of*** voted "ungrammatical" if we were talking about this current sentence! :)

Comment: I would interpret it as "It was cute.  [It was] like a shy teenager."  Nothing "ungrammatical" about it -- using the same subject & verb for a list of adjective/adverbal phrases is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Is it a common mistake of non-English speakers to think this is ungrammatical?

Comment: @augurar We had a question recently on how meaningful it is to label all constructions 'grammatical' or 'ungrammatical'. In the thread, a renowned linguist was quoted as having postulated a five-point gradience of acceptability. I'd say most linguists and many anglophones would consider 'It was cute, like a shy teenager.' unacceptable. Comparing 'It' (one assumes an action) with a person is not how English works.

Comment: This is casual speech and it sounds grammatical to me. I'd paraphrase it as "*Dont' be ashamed. It was cute, in the way a shy teenager's behavior is cute.*" If you are learning English and you are reminding yourself that every sentence should have a subject, and a verb; that is a good rule of thumb but is not always observed in casual speech.

Comment: Incidentally, the proposed alternative "It was cute, you were like a shy teenager" is a [comma splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice), which is sometimes frowned upon as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an ungrammatical expression.  The sentence is a combination of the phrases "It was cute" and "It was like a shy teenager".

One could consider this a case of [unclear pronoun reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20150402065447/http://www.writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/CommonErrors_PronRef.html), which would generally be considered more of a stylistic than grammatical error.